# Querying a row as "selected" within Interactive Grid

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

I currently have an interactive grid whose purpose is to allow the user to select rows to do further manipulation.  However, the list of rows is quite long so I have a select list that can be used to filter the list based on categories of rows and I ran into a bit of an issue.

Let's say I selected 3 rows from category A then moved to Category C and selected 2, then I want to check which rows I selected from A, but when I select Category A none of the rows I selected previously are shown as selected.  It makes sense that this happens since selecting the filter re-queries the interactive grid but I was wondering if it would be possible to add a condition in the pl/sql function query that would query a row as selected.

If this isn't possible would it be possible to write a dynamic action that re-selected the rows?

Any guidance on how to either "query a row as selected" or select a row via dynamic action, process, etc would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One option might be to alter table and add column, let's call it `CB_SELECTED` which gets `1` if row is selected (or `0` if it isn't, which should be its default value).

Select list item you have would set it via dynamic action and requery the IG.

---

Another, maybe/possibly better option would be to use a collection which would contain rows (actually, their primary key values) you select. IG's query would have yet another `WHERE` condition that returns rows contained in that collection.

---

Hopefully, someone else will have new ideas.

Comment: This could work but I want to visual effect of the selected row to be displayed if you know the code needed to select a row automatically then that combined with this solution would be perfect

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to set a row as selected for an interactive grid in pl/sql. That only can be done using javascript - but not easily.

I think you're trying to mix 2 business actions into a single component: (1) filtering and selecting - and refiltering and selecting and (2) displaying all selected rows. My suggestion would be to use a separate region for each of those business actions (or use a page wizard with 2 or more pages)

1. A region that is used for filtering and selecting. You can use an IG for this but it will be a lot of javascript coding. My preference would be an interactive report or classic report with a dynamic action on a column.
2. A region that shows all selected records so far.

I would follow the approach @Littlefoot is also suggesting, which is to store the selected values in a collection - this could be the source for the 2nd report then.

Comment: If using a second report is required I would pursue this but I would rather use the javascript option, do you know of any resources I could reference on the Javascript code you are referring to?

Comment: search for blogs, here on so and forums.oracle.com and the docs. There are no dedicated resources that I'm aware of. I don't think there is even a way to set the selected row programmatically (with javascript). As I stated, this isn't that simple you could be on for a long ride... with no guarantee for success